# ¿Es posible subir una pagina web a cpanel sin un subdominio?

Tags: hosting, cpanel

¡Hola!, soy nuevo en subir paginas web a un hosting,y quisiera saber si es posible subir la pagina web con todos sus archivos por cpanel en el administrador de archivos , y subirlo por ejemplo en la carpeta dominio principal , en este caso tendria que subirlo al public_html y hay crear la carpeta y subir todos mis archivos para cargar la pagina web?

Si fuera ese el caso , la extension por url tendría que ser asi? https://dominioPrincipal.com/carpetaPrueba/index.php ? De antemano Muchas Gracias!

(Editado)

[image: Carpeta dentro de public_html]

[image: archivos y carpetas dentro de la carpeta views]

En cada uno de las carpetas que aparece en views hay archivos php que hace las funcionalidades de lo que es el CRUD , De antemano Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Por favor muestra cómo estás acomodando los archivos en las carpetas, _esto sí podría ser con una captura.

Comment: @Alfabravo Gracias por responder!, Ya está editado!

Comment: Si tu carpeta root en tu sistema local es `System/` entonces debes subir todo su contenido dentro de tu **public_html/** en cpanel (pero no la carpeta System/ en si, solo lo que contiene, a menos que quieras acceder a tu web mediante http://midominio.com/System). Dicho de otro modo, si dices que quieres acceder a tu web mediante esta url: `https://dominioPrincipal.com/carpetaPrueba/index.php` entonces debes subir el contenido de tu carpeta root local a `public_html/carpetaPrueba/` creándola antes si es necesario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En efecto, si tu dominio es `example.com` y quieres subir tu página web en la carpeta test, debes crear la carpeta test en tu `public_html/` `www/` (que se conoce comunmente como **DocumentRoot**)

Y luego puedes acceder a la misma a través de `example.com/test`

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la respuesta!, produje lo que indicaba pero me salta que no se produjo : estos son los errores : La dirección URL solicitada no se encontró en este servidor.

Además, se encontró un error 404 Not Found al intentar usar un ErrorDocument para manejar la solicitud.

Comment: ¿puedes mostrar cuál es el dominio y la estructura de los directorios?

Comment: Hay edite como estan  acomodos los archivos en las carpetas del administrador de archivos! , De antemano Gracias!!

Comment: ¿Qué es esa carpeta system? ¿estás utilizando algún framework? no parecía nada de eso en la pregunta original

Comment: La carpeta System es cualquier carpeta , no tiene mucha relevancia , probablemente sea mejor cambiarle el nombre jaja , puede ser sistema_gestion o cualquier otro!

Comment: Pero no vemos lo que está por encima de esa carpeta...